# Organizing Media Files on Category basis

Tags: wordpress

I've just started learning the WordPress CMS, i have a small PHP programming background and i wanted to masters in WordPress now. for the learning sake, i have started a project on my local server, Where user can register, login and upload images afterwards.

My Question is that, how do i organize all media uploads to a Category Base directory, all uploads should go to a specific directory based on user selection. If user selects "PLACES" category then the uploaded image/file should go to Places directory.

-Thanks

**UPDATE**

If the above option can not be achieved then how about creating a directory with post slug? like **`year/month/day/post-slug/images goes here`**

Answer (score 0):

Only your written articles can be sorted by category. 
Unfortunately there is no folder system for images. The only thing you can do is writing a post, import a image into the article and assign a category to the article. But anyway, assigning a category to a image is not necessary.

Comment: OK, i know this and thats why i asked the experienced programmers over here. may be someone did it.

Comment: Can you suggest any other option where i can easily manage the images with out having an year/month basis?

Comment: Probably this plugin is something you want: https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-plus/screenshots/

Comment: This plugin looks good, but its best suited for admins only. A user should not have a whole access to the library. i have updated my question

Comment: You can restrict user permissions using another plugin called 'User Role Editor' https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: Just remove the checkboxes, which refer to the media library plus plugin